# Airxmail, SMTP, and crossdomain.xml Confusion

Tags: apache-flex, smtp, flexbuilder

I've created a Flex app which uses Coltware's airxmail to send SMTP messages.  It calls a locally-hosted SMTP server (hmailserver), which relays the email out as appropriate.  When run within the Flash Builder environment, everything works as intended.  I can also send email both locally and remotely from the SMTP server using telnet, so I know that it's not a problem with the server.

When hosted on the email server box itself, outside of the GUI, the app fails to send email.  I've created a crossdomain.xml file to allow this access, but I don't believe it's configured properly.

The Flex code:

```
  sender = new SMTPSender();
  sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.HOST,"192.168.10.10");
  sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.PORT,25);  
  sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.AUTH,true);
  sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.USERNAME,"emailuser@domain.com");
  sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.PASSWORD,"password");


  var message:MimeMessage = new MimeMessage();
  message.contentType = ContentType.MULTIPART_ALTERNATIVE;
  var from:INetAddress = new INetAddress("emailuser@server.com","Fake Name");

  message.setFrom(from);
  var toRecpt:INetAddress = new INetAddress(email,username);
  message.addRcpt(RecipientType.TO,toRecpt);

  message.setSubject(subject);


  var partHtml:MimeTextPart = message.createTextPart();
  partHtml.setHtmlText(body);

  sender.send(message);           
  sender.close();
```

When I add listeners for the various SMTPEvents, none of them fire.  I think this is due to a lack of permissions or poor configuration within the crossdomain.xml file, which is set up as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy (View Source for full doctype...)> 
- <cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="192.168.10.10" to-ports="25" secure="true" /> 
  <allow-access-to domain="192.168.10.10" secure="false" /> 

  </cross-domain-policy>
```

I've found a number of questions like this, but few posted answers.  I'm convinced it's something obvious.  Any ideas as to how I can proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Locally hosted?  if you're not using 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1', that is not locally hosted.  Seems to me you're trying to connect to a server within your network, but not on the machine running the Air application.

I'm fairly sure that the STMP sender is using Sockets to connect to the server, so I think what you need to do is load a manual [socket policy file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html), but I'm not 100% sure.  You might want to try to get the crossdomain file completely open (by using '*' instead).  Are there any errors that pop up or it just doesn't connect?

Comment: By "locally hosted", I meant that the mail server and the Apache instance serving the Flex app are running on the same box.  Shouldn't matter, but...  I'll try using a socket policy file as well.  I receive no errors.  When I check the SMTP server logs, the client has opened a connection, but immediately closes it upon seeing the SMTP announcement from the mailserver.

Comment: If they're running on the same box, why not use 'localhost' instead of an IP address? Also, since this project is open source, I say download the code and debug it.

Comment: I cut a bit out of the crossdomain file before posting it.  It contains identically-scoped entries for localhost, the IP address, the fully qualifed domain name (www.test.com, for example), the domain (test.com), and the virtual host that Apache uses for the HTML files hosting the Flex app.  So far as debugging the code, I'm not a Flex developer.  I'm hoping that a SME can jump in and help out with what seems to be a structural issue.

Comment: I'm not talking about the crossdomain for the localhost, I mean this: `sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.HOST,"192.168.10.10");`